# Hot module replacement in angular 8

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-hmr

I am currently starting a new angular project, and I would like to implement **[HMR (Hot Module Replacement)](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/enabling-hot-module-replacement-angular-6/)**.

I have done each and every step described in the **[tutorial](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/enabling-hot-module-replacement-angular-6/)**, but I get the following errors:

> Using the **[latest angular](https://www.google.com/search?q=latest%20angular%20version&oq=latest%20angular%20version&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2975j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** version. **[Fresh project setup](https://angular.io/cli)**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you in good directory ?

Comment: @Freestyle09 , fresh project setup , root directory. Pretty easy to reproduce.

Comment: Have you checked that only 'ng serve' is working ? 'Project does not exist' is weird error

Comment: @Freestyle09 , `ng serve` works, it starts the project as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **NOTE:** I have found **[the most relevant tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr)** (in my opinion) , because I also swapped my code snippets with the ones described in it, so please use this one for reference.

The problem with the `Project does not exist.` error was that I have forgot to add the local name (directory name) of the project in **angular.json**

[image]

Must become:

[image]

And, voila:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed the the most relevant tutorial and the answer you give and it works completely find.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty good in this case: `project does not exist.`

1. Check your angular.json file.

   a. find key "defaultProject". it should be name of your project.

   b. find key projects. by default, it should have only object with your project name.
2. Either you can add a new project with required configuration 
   or
   just rename both defaultProject value and project project object key.

   [image: angular.json project]

If you have set HMR correctly then all should go well otherwise you will find below error:

> Configuration 'hmr' is not set in the workspace.